# convert negative scientific notation 1.3E-2 to float?

Tags: python, floating-point, scientific-notation

I understand that I can convert a number in scientific notation to a float with `float` like this:

```
>>> x = 1.3e8
>>> float(x)
130000000.0
```

Then, why can I not do the same thing with a negative exponent?

```
>>> x = 1.3e-8
>>> x
1.3e-08
>>> float(x)
1.3e-08
```

I would have expected for `float(x)` in the last case to give `0.000000013`

Comment: It should be noted that `1.3e-08` is a float. The difference is just in how it is printed.

Comment: `0.000000013 == 1.3e-8` is `True`. This question seems odd. In neither of your cases does `float(x)` actually do anything.

Comment: You can use `format(x, '.9f')`.

Comment: sure, the question should have been "how to print it like a float without using scientific notation". apologies for the confusion. I know it's a float! thanks for all the answers below. So @JohnColeman what is more odd: my question or the way python behaves in the above example? ;-) why should it print one way with a positive exponent but in another with a negative one? Again, I understand the number is the same, but, just...*why*?

Comment: @FlorianOswald Good question. Perhaps the rationale for positive exponents is that such numbers should have a representation which looks like the representation of the integer that they round to. For numbers with negative exponents, they typically round to 0, so that wouldn't be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`1.3e-8` is a floating point literal (i.e. it directly creates a `float` object) so you don't need to wrap it in a `float()`. The Python shell simply returns the default string representation of a float. To force the fixed-point notation, you can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), although you may need to specify the precision:

```
>>> '{:.9f}'.format(1.3e-8)
'0.000000013'
```

Comment: This works for this specific case, but what of `1.3e-12`

Comment: If you know the max precision, you can do something like this: `'{:.20f}'.format(1.3e-8).rstrip('0')`

Comment: just worth to note

Answer (score 0):

It is already a float, it just stays represented in scientific notation

```
print(type(1.3e8)) # <class 'float'>
print(type(1.3e-8)) # <class 'float'>
print(0.000000013)  # 1.3e-08
```

Comment: The intended question might be to find a way to print the float using non-scientific notation.

Comment: @YannickBuehler that may be the case

Answer (score 0):

The following function deals with an arbitrary number of floating points.

```
def displayfloat(x):
    # format numbers > 1.
    if str(x).find('+') > -1:
        return '{:.1f}'.format(x)
    e_idx = str(x).find('e')
    # format numbers > 1e-05
    if e_idx == -1:
        return str(x)
    # format numbers < 1e-05
    minus_idx = str(x).find('-')
    shift = e_idx
    if str(x).find('.') > -1:
        shift -= 1
    decimalpoints = -int(str(x)[str(x).find('-'):]) - 1 + shift
    floatformat = '{:.'+str(decimalpoints)+'f}'
    return floatformat.format(x)
# exmaples
displayfloat(1e-5) # --> '0.00001'
displayfloat(1.1e-5) # --> '0.000011'
displayfloat(1e+5) # --> '100000.0'
```